# Why does github compare my branch with the default branch instead of the source branch from which it was created?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-checkout

I am trying to create a new `test` branch from the `kinetic-devel` branch of the [the following repository](https://github.com/rickstaa/panda_moveit_config). I do this by using the following git command:

```
git checkout -b test kinetic-devel
```

When checking out the new branch on GitHub.com I expected the GitHub interface to show a comparison of the newly created `test` branch with the `kinetic-devel` source branch:

[image: right_comparison]

Instead, GitHub shows me a comparison with the default `melodic-devel` branch instead of the `kinetic-devel` source branch from which it was created:

[image: wrong_comparison]

Judging from the git log the `test` branch is indeed a child of the `kinetic-devel` branch and not the`melodic-devel` branch.

### Question

Is this only an interface related problem or am I doing something wrong while creating the new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this only an interface related problem or am I doing something wrong while creating the new branch?

Rather the former: this repository has a default branch (visible in [`rickstaa/panda_moveit_config/branches`](https://github.com/rickstaa/panda_moveit_config/branches)) set to `melodic-devel`.

So it is the default branch against which any PR would be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So as long as I create my new branch using `checkout kinetic-devel; branch test` or `checkout -b test kinetic-devel`. Will the branch always be relative to the `kinetic-devel` branch?

Comment: @arcety You had selected the right answer ;) Your branch will be created from kinetic-devel, and can be pushed as its own name, in order to represent a new PR branch. You can then trigger a PR against any branch of the original repo you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating on that. The only thing that intrigues me is that the original [kinetic-devel](https://github.com/rickstaa/panda_moveit_config/tree/kinetic-devel) branch of my fork is compared to the [kinetic-devel](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/tree/kinetic-devel) branch of the upstream repository. Could this be because the `kinetic-devel` branch is present on the upstream repository itself?

Comment: @arcety I suppose so indeed. The best practice, when you do a PR, is to create a branch (from a known branch like upstream/kinetic-devel) with a name unique for that PR. That allows the maintainer to distinguish what they will be integrating, later on.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are tryng to create your branch starting from melodic-devel.
The right command to set the track branch is :

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

To correctly track you branch you should use this command:

```
git checkout -b test --track origin/kinetic-devel
```

or:

```
git checkout kinetic-devel
git branch -b test
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I tried both methods but GitHub keeps showing the wrong comparison. I, therefore, suspect it is an interface problem as the git log is equal to that of the `kinetic-devel` branch.